# Use existing ODBC connection passed by handle

Tags: c#, database, odbc

I have (unmanaged) application, that is using ODBC to acces database. This application will call some C# (managed) subprogram with one parameter: ODBC handle of connection that the application is using, so subprogram can use it to connect to database too.

Unfortunately `System.Data.OdbcConnection` can't be initialized by handle of existing one.

It is possible to use existing ODBC connection, or I have to create new one form connection string?

Does it even make sense to use old connection instead of creating new one?

Comment: I would say just pass the connection string.

Comment: If connection pooling is in place, and you use the same connection string, you are likely to get the same connection.  Otherwise, it's a small matter if you don't.

Comment: If a SQL server is licensed by the number of congruent connections creation of new one could be very expensive operation. Connection pooling looks promising, but if I understand it right it reusing of connection is implied by closing it first.